# Вывод содержания папки на главную страницу

Tags: php

Такая ситуация, у меня есть скрипт создания статей.
Он создает статью и ложит в папку /articles/
Мне нужно, чтобы статьи, после создания попадали на главную страницу.
Вот код создания статей,

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitBtn'])){
    ob_start();
    include "../index.php";
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    file_put_contents('../articles/' . $_POST['filename'] . '.php', $html);
    file_put_contents('../opisaniya/' . $_POST['filename'] . '.txt', $_POST['opisanie']);
    echo '<p align="center"><a href="../articles/' . $_POST['filename'] . '.php">Перейти </a> к статье</p>';
    }
    ?>
```

Как мне вывести на главную, созданный заголовок и содержание?

```
[PHP]<p align="center"><b> <?php echo $_POST['title']; ?></b></p>
        <p align="center">
        <div width="70%">
        <p align="center" <?php echo'style="font-size:'.$_POST['size'].'px;"'?>><?php echo $_POST['article']; ?></p>
        <br /><br />
        </div>
        </p>[/PHP]
```

Comment: а где хранится заголовок?

Comment: создается новый файл, по типу главной страницы, в созданный файл записывается заголовок

Answer (score 0):

1. Вариант

Сканим папку со статьями

```
$files = glob(/path/to/articles-dir/*);
if ($files) {
    foreach($files as $file) {
        // парсим файлик в надежде найти заголовок
    }
}
```

2. Вариант

Т.к. вы сохраняете описания в отдельные файлики, почему бы не делать такого же с заголовками?

Тогда с помощью того же `glob` ищем заголовки и описания.

3. Вариант

Но что если еще понадобится дата? или еще какие-нибудь данные? Или если будет очень много статей? Тогда лучше использовать какую-нибудь базу данных.